# Firebase Error (https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{siteName}/installations) {403 | failed} in ReactJs Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

We have a ReactJs project (17.0.2) with firebase (^8.9.1).
Service 'https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{siteName}/installations' has no response. some time give 403,
And 'https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{siteName}/namespaces/fireperf:fetch?key=XYZ' give CORS error sometime...

we tried other firebase's version but didn't solve the problem.